i think its a import error correct me if i'm wrong

AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?

When I'm installing pandas module in my pycharm community edition, this is popping up. What can we do to deal with that?
import pandas as pd

def sendEmail():
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.read_excel("Code File exmp..xlxs")
    print(df)

